# MongoDB Update Query

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

In MongoDB I want to update the new balance + old balance for `User1`.

**Example:**

Table Before Update:

```
Name    Balance
User1   10
```

New Balance = 15

Table After Update:

```
Name    Balance
User1   25
```

**Note:** I want without select the old balance row in the table

Any one help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the $inc operator to do this. For example:

```
$ mongo
MongoDB shell version: 3.2.7
connecting to: test
replset:PRIMARY> db.test.insert({Name: "User1", Balance: 10})
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })
replset:PRIMARY> db.test.update({Name: "User1"}, {$inc: {Balance: 15}});
WriteResult({ "nMatched" : 1, "nUpserted" : 0, "nModified" : 1 })
replset:PRIMARY> db.test.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("57769008dca27b8fad7443ef"), "Name" : "User1", "Balance" : 25 }
```